# Read Core Data object attribute take too much time

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, core-data, instruments

I have one object `Test` that is stored in CoreData.

For example `Test` has `@propeties short indexForAttribute1 ..... indexForAttribute6`

When manipulate with it I noticed that it take a lot of time to read his properties.

code is simple:

```
self.dimensionIndex = test.indexForAttribute1;
```

I guess it has to have something whit core data not fetch all attributes for all objects so I try

```
[fetchRequest setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"indexForAttribute1",@"indexForAttribute2",@"indexForAttribute3",@"indexForAttribute4",@"indexForAttribute5",@"indexForAttribute6", nil]];
```

but nothing is better.

See image from time profiler

[image]

EDIT : larger image

[image]

Comment: the screenshot is a bit too small to read. If these attributes are not relationships, which attribute implies, the `setRelationshipWithKeyPathsForPrefetching`won't help. How long exactly does it take to read? uses `dimensionIndex` a custom setter?

Comment: I add larger image for interesting part. No, `dimensionIndex` don't use custom setter. If I use `dimensionIndex = 10` then works faster.

Comment: and how much time does it consume? the new image doesn't show that. dimensionIndex = 10... is dimensionIndex an object or scalar?

Comment: it takes something like 275 ms. I know this is seam to be little but I run it for a lot of times. `dimensionIndex` is int.

Comment: you can use Instruments to show you CoreData fetch activity, that should help to outline if the slowness comes from fetching :|

Comment: In instrument it show like it don't fach data in this line.

Comment: so probably time is consumed somewhere else.

Comment: ok, but where. Do you have some suggestion where to look ?

Comment: Use Instruments to identify where your code takes all the time. Since it is probably not related to fetching, it must be somewhere else.